# Why this code would fail or not fail?

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008, t-sql

What is the best way to write it ? Since I have written it but I suspect it's not a good way.

Scenario: I have written a store procedure which simply `INSERTS` a record into `TABLE` and then picks last inserted Primary key and return it to front end application i.e.

```
      @parameter1 int, 
      @Parameter2 smallint,
      @Error varchar(MAX) output,
      @OutPutParamter int Output

Begin
      Begin Try
           insert into table1
           values (@parameter1, @parameter2)

           Set @OutPutParamter= Scope_Identity()

      End Try

      Begin Catch
           set @Error= Select Error_Message()
           set @OutPutParameter= 0
      End Catch
End
```

Now question is that how `@OutPutParameter` would be treated ? What hazards in returning a value could be ?

Comment: I don't see anything wrong with your procedure.

Comment: The main hazard I can see is, when you try to put `@OutPutParamter = 0` value in any child table that has foreign with `table1`

Comment: @MotoGP I don't, it's just what I am returning in case of exception

Comment: Then nothing wrong with your current query

Comment: 1) define column list at insert statement 2) remove `select` before `error_message()` - it is unnecessary and this code would compile only with additional parenthesis.

Answer (score 0):

1. The query you write is correct.
2. `Scope_Identity()` will get the id which the record insert into the table
3. `@OutPutParamter` is a output type variable, after run the SP, you can find the id from `@OutPutParamter`.
4. You also can use a local variable to get the id and use select to return the value